# Static controller multiple routes/single controller

Tags: laravel

I tried to find an answer that does the job, but the ones I found didn't really feel right to me, I have a static part of my site which I can arrange the route normally as in the code below.

it seems so messy to repeat the same route for more 7 pages, there got to be a smarter way to do it, I need to some opinions, maybe a controller with a slug or something, but I don't quite understand how to do it with a static part of the site like this.

Thanks.

```
Route::get('/first/home', function()
{
    return View::make('/first.home');
});

 Route::get('/first/aboutus', function()
{
    return View::make('/first.aboutus');
});
Route::get('/first/contact', function()
{
    return View::make('/first.contact');
});
```

Comment: If you have a Controller that handles your requests, you can refactor to `Route::get("/route", "ExampleController@getRoute");`, which, repeated 7 times is a lot cleaner than repeating a `function(){ ... }` block.

Comment: You wrote: "it seems so messy to repeat the same route for more 7 pages" => plz clarify: Are you looking to have multiple instances of every page?

Comment: @TimLewis I don't understand, can you please explain a bit more how to use your answer.

Comment: @clusterBuddy no, just a few static pages in a specific section in the site, and I'm trying to find a smart and easy way to make an efficient route.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling your coming from WP, or maybe i'm wrong. In anycase, Laravel has a diff. ballgame in terms of serving static pages.

Now after your clarification, I would recommend you group your routes, as follows:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'first'], function () {
    Route::get('(.*)', 'HomeController@getPageByName');
});
```

in `HomeController` You can write the following function:

```
function getPageByName(Request $request) 
{
    $pageName = $request->path();
    //since your url does not begin with the page but with 'first',
    //best is to turn this into an array.
    $parsedPath = explode("/",$pageName)
    $data = 'any data you want to pass';
    if(View::exists($pageName[1] ){
       return view($pageName[1] , compact($data));
    } else {
        abort(404)
    }
}
```

Essentially your url would look like this, if you want page one:

`http://example.com/first/home`

Now Laravel will look for `views/home.blade`

Let me know if this helps your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I need to clarify more, sorry I'm new to programming, and no I didn't come from wordpress, I hate it more than you can possibly imagine.

Comment: don't hate anything my friend, everything has a purpose, WP is awesome for certain stuff. Please clarify.

Comment: @ibrahimMohamed - function is ready for you. notice i'm using `'(.*)'` to capture anything after `/first`, if that page exists, it will render, if not, it'll redirect to Laravel's default 404. I hope this helps you. going to sleep but will revert back here tmrw

Comment: it's giving 404 and I don't know why  Route::group(['prefix' => 'first'], function () {
    Route::get('(.*)', 'HomeController@getNumberPage');
}); /////////  $pageName = $request->path()
        if(View::exists($pageName ){
           return view($pageName);
        } else {
            //throw an exception of missing page.
        }

Comment: @ibrahimMohamed the answer was edited, from the reply above here I can see that you took something irrelevant. try again and let me know. Also if this is the right answer, please mark it so, thx mate!

Comment: @clusteBuddy its not working, as for the $data, i don't need to pass anything, it's just the route for the static page.

Comment: @ibrahimMohamed - don't abandon the question mate... :/ If I have it right make it the answer, if not, i'll fix accordingly.